# Glare node, why is the glare in front of other objects?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes

I am setting up a node tree in the Compositor for some post-production effects. I have the earth on one render layer and a UV sphere with stars and a Sun Object (emitting light) on another render layer. Now I have this effect when muting this Glare Node. The ID mask is for this Sun object.

[image]

This looks allright to me. But when the Glare Node is activated then this horizontal glare beam looks like before instead behind the earth.

[image]

I am quite sure the sun object is behind the earth (seen from the camera position). What is going wrong here ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Nothing is wrong, that's how glare works.**

In real life, [lens glare (or flare)](http://www.cambridgeincolour.com/tutorials/lens-flare.htm) is an effect produced by a camera or your eyes when looking at a very bright spot.  It is caused by internal reflections and defects within the lens.

[image]
*Image by [cmwphotography](http://cmwphotography.deviantart.com/art/Sunset-Glare-256479170).*

Those streaks are not physical things in 3-dimensional space emitting light, they are introduced by the camera, so they can't appear behind anything, they are introduced onto the image within the lens.

Comment: yes I know lens flare (I am a photographer). You are right .....stupid me (Grrrr))> Because of the name "glare" I thought it had something to do with the object but it's about the lens of course :)

Comment: "Glare" because "flare" was taken ;-)